# C - local thread variable is shared

Tags: c, multithreading

I've been trying to pass a variable to threads ,but the instant a second thread is created the value changes despite it being created as a constant variable.

```
//for the first user
if (flag == 0) {
    //store the socket
    cl_sc[0] = client_sock_desc;
    //set id
    whichOne[0] = 0;
    puts("Client accepted");
    //second user ,same procedure
}
else if (flag == 1) {
    cl_sc[1] = client_sock_desc;
    whichOne[0] = 1;
    puts("Client accepted");
}

//create thread and pass cl_sc as arguement
pthread_t sTcThread;
pthread_create(&sTcThread, NULL, server_to_client, (void*)whichOne);
```

And here is the thread implimentation

```
void* server_to_client(void* socket_desc)
{
    //make the arguement readable
    const int* whichOne = (int*)socket_desc;
    //one int for retrieved data and one for his socket
    int retrieve, socket = cl_sc[whichOne[0]];
    //chat buddy socket
    int palsSocket;

    //the actual data
    char data[DATA_LENGTH];
    //free the string
    memset(data, 0, DATA_LENGTH);
    for (;;) {
        //set accordingly
        if (whichOne[0] == 0) {
            palsSocket = cl_sc[1];
        }
        else if (whichOne[0] == 1) {
            palsSocket = cl_sc[0];
        }
        printf("Im %d to join my socket is %d and my pals socket is %d\n", whichOne[0], socket, palsSocket);
    }
}
```

Results of the execution

> Client accepted Im 0 to join my socket is 4 and my pals socket is 0
>   Client accepted Im 1 to join my socket is 5 and my pals socket is 4

But the moment thread 0 is activated this happens

> Im 1 to join my socket is 4 and my pals socket is 4

Changing the whichOne constant to 1.

Solved as such thanks to the answers and comments .

```
    int *whichOneImported = (int *) socket_desc;
    int whichOne = whichOneImported[0];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`const int *whichOne = (int *) socket_desc;` guarantees that `whichOne` isn't changed by an instruction of your subroutine, but not by another thread, since it points on a shared memory area (you pass the *address* to the `whichOne` array when you create your thread, and you modify its value afterwards when `flag == 1`)

you set `whichOne[0] = 1;` in the other thread, and I'm not sure of the logic but maybe you meant:

```
whichOne[flag] = flag;
```

and then

```
pthread_create(&sTcThread, NULL, server_to_client, (void*) (whichOne+flag));
```

to separate the data

Or make a allocated copy of `whichOne` prior to running the thread.

Comment: I think a bit more exposition could be useful on the "why", but is the correct answer.

Comment: So the pointer is a constant, but not the actual value .  Is there a way I can make the value constant?

Comment: I think you defined the `whichOne[3]` slots for this, but not using them.

Comment: The other slots are used elsewhere. I want the value of whichOne[0] in its thread to be separate but seems like this isn't a working solution

Comment: then double the thread slots / pass a "flag" indexed pointer to your routine. Also: you can duplicate the array if you want to fix the values.